What guidelines would support not having large video content in close proximity to a form a user needs to fill out?
If a website has a large scale video that is playing automatically, in close proximity to a search form which a user needs to fill out (ie. directly behind and above the search form), my assumption is that it would distract a user and make it harder for a user to fill in the search form successfully.
I'm struggling to find best practise guidelines around this to support my case and given the complexity of a search form, we may struggle to prototype it, to user test it (and user test it on people with a range of needs).
I'm therefore asking if anyone is aware of any best practise guidelines around this or reasons to help support why this could be a bad thing from an accessibility and usability point of view.

WCAG 2.1 SC 2.2.2 gets you close:

For any moving, blinking or scrolling information that (1) starts automatically, (2) lasts more than five seconds, and (3) is presented in parallel with other content, there is a mechanism for the user to pause, stop, or hide it unless the movement, blinking, or scrolling is part of an activity where it is essential

